# Evaluate Machine Learning Text Classifier

Tags: python, nlp, logistic-regression, text-classification

I have built a binary text classifier. Trained it to recognize sentences for clients based on 'New' or 'Return'. My issue is that real data may not always have a clear distinction between new or return, even to an actual person reading the sentence. 
My model was trained to 0.99% accuracy with supervised learning using Logistic Regression.

```
#train model
def train_model(classifier, feature_vector_train, label, feature_vector_valid,valid_y, is_neural_net=False):
    classifier.fit(feature_vector_train, label)
    predictions = classifier.predict(feature_vector_valid)
    if is_neural_net:
        predictions = predictions.argmax(axis=-1)
    return classifier , metrics.accuracy_score(predictions, valid_y)

# Linear Classifier on Count Vectors
    model, accuracy = train_model(linear_model.LogisticRegression(), xtrain_count, train_y, xtest_count,test_y)
    print (':::  Accuracy on Test Set   :::')
    print ('Linear Classifier, BoW Vectors: ', accuracy)
```

And this would give me an accuracy of 0.998.
I now can pass a whole list of sentences to test this model and it would catch if the sentences has a **new** or **return** word yet I need an evaluation metric because some sentences will have no chance of being **new** or **return** as real data is messy as always.

My question is: **What evaluation metrics can I use so that each new sentence that gets passed through the model shows a score?**
Right now I only use the following code

```
with open('realdata.txt', 'r') as f:
    samples = f.readlines()
vecs = count_vect.transform(sentence)
visit = model.predict(vecs)
num_to_label= {0:'New', 1:'Return'}
for s, p in zip(sentence, visit):
    #printing each sentence with the predicted label
    print(s + num_to_label[p])
```

For example I would expect

```
Sentence                      Visit          (Metric X)
New visit 2nd floor           New             0.95
Return visit Evening          Return          0.98
Afternoon visit North         New             0.43
```

Therefore I'd know to **not** trust those will metrics below a certain percentage because the tool isnt reliable.

Comment: It seems like a human labeler would want 3 categories: new, return, and unspecified. Why not make a three class classifier?

Comment: @SamH. how would you train unspecified data? just add random data that isnt related to new or return?

Comment: Ideally I would re-label some existing data. In the example you give, "Afternoon visit North" I would label "unspecified"

Answer (score 0):

You can use predict_proba() instead of predict(). This will give you probability estimates of your predictions for each possible label.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html